# Mathematica unable to realize simple distributional relationship

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I was trying to find the CDF for the following problem:

```
In[1]:= Probability[e1 - Log[e2 + e3] <= t, {
  e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1],
  e2 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1],
  e3 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]

Out[1]= Probability[
 e1 - Log[e2 + e3] <= 
  t, {e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
  e2 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
  e3 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]
```

Clearly Mathematica didn't like that.
Then I rephrased it as

```
In[2]:= Probability[e1 - Log[c] <= t, {
  e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1],
  c \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[2, 1]}]

Out[2]= E^-E^-t
```

which apparently wasn't a problem
Note that the sum of two standard exponentials is a gamma distribution with parameters (2,1). So the two problems should have the same solution.

Is there some way I can help Mathematica realize this? Maybe I need to specify something about the numbers not being complex or something?

(Note, I get the same results whether I'm using Mathematica 12.1.1.0 on my own machine, or Wolfram Cloud.)

**Update:** If I switch the order of the arguments, it also stops working with the GammaDistribution:

```
In[1]:= Probability[
 e1 - Log[c] <= t, {c \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[2, 1], 
  e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]
Out[1]= Probability[
 e1 - Log[c] <= t, {c \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[2, 1], 
  e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}]
```

It's definitely very brittle.

Comment: Funny `CDF[TransformedDistribution[
  e1 - Log[e2 + e3], {e1 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
   e2 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1], 
   e3 \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}], t]` works.

Comment: If you add `Assumptions -> t > 0`, it works.  (Windows 10 12.3.1.0 and 13.2.0)

Comment: Thanks! Both of these work! But JimB's solution is faster :)

Comment: Is t being postive required?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников good point. The CDF is valid for all $t$, also negative.

Comment: I was too strict.  Using `Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals` makes it work.